# Creating URL Slugs in AWS Lamba / Node functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cakephp, aws-lambda, clean-urls

I am created my first aws lambda/serverless app as I want it to scale but perform like an MVC app and blog with many pages. Perfer a tech news site where each article is a separate url as opposed to an AJAX Gmail type of application

Is it possible to do this? I don't want my urls to be mydomain.com/ride.thml but instead to be mydomain.com/pick-up-wild-rydes-unicorn.

Any tutorials besides the aws wild rydes one would be helpful.

I have used cakephp in the past but worry about scaling it horizontally (or any mvc type application).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways, essentially you need to use the slug as a URL parameter variable.

1. Create a Hosted Zone for your domain in Route 53
2. Create an API in API Gateway and put the slug part as a URL Parameter
3. The routing will probably require a stage directory (e.g. `v1`) this is ok.
4. The API will have a generic AWS URL + your stage.
5. Assign your Route 53 custom domain `<your domain>` to direct to `<API Gateway url>/<stage>/` such that you only need to request `<your domain>/<slug>`.
6. Access the `{slug}` parameter from your Lambda function and serve the appropriate content

Comment: When using custom domains you don't need to specify the stage on the URI itself. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Comment: That's right, sorry I didn't explain too well..edited